# Validation criterias in simple linear regression in r

Tags: r, validation, regression

I plotted a simple linear regression in ggplot both for the entire data and training set and test set. But, the problem is that it just provides a plot, nothing more like RMSE, R2, etc. How can I compare? How can I measure the performance of my simple linear regression prediction model?

Comment: Please read the R manual.  `lm()` is the function for estimating linear models.  `ggplot` just provides a quick fit for visual inspection.  Chapter 11 covers statistical modelling https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Please make an answer out of that comment so people can see, this question already has it's answer and other people can upvote. If you are kind, you might even mention `summary` to extract R-quared from the `lm` model...

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` is one of the most popular alternatives for producing plots in R. As George Savva has pointed out, computing statistics in R does not need `ggplot2` nor should the latter be preferably used for that.

The following example shows how to compute a simple linear OLS regression and how to gain $R^2$ and RMSE (and additionally AIC and BIC even though you did not ask for those two):

```
#some example data
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4.5,4.6,7)
y <- c(.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 4.0, 6,7)

linear.model <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(linear.model)

# find R^2
summary(linear.model)$r.squared

# RSME is the square root of the mean of squared residuals
sqrt(mean(linear.model$residuals^2))

# Akaike Information Criterion
AIC(linear.model)

# so-called BIC or SBC (Schwarz's Bayesian criterion).
BIC(linear.model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimating and inspecting a linear model in R is described in chapter 11 of the R manual here:  [cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf).  If you are using R for statistical modelling you should read this.

In short though, the function to estimate linear models is `lm()`. Once you have estimated your model the `summary()` function will report R-squared, residual error, etc.  ggplot is for plotting, not for model building and diagnostics.